# Retrieve ImageByte from SQL Server Database to DataGridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datagridview

I am using `ASP.NET` Visual Basic language and I want to retrieve my data from `SQL Server 2008`. During retrieving the data from the Database I noticed that the `image/picture` did not load on the `DataGridView`. It only retrieves text data but image data is not present. These is my sample `SQL Script`:

```
sql = "SELECT em_Picture, em_EmployeeID, em_LastName + ', ' + em_FirstName " & _
"From [T_EmployeeMaster] Where em_EmploymentStatus <> 'RS' "
```

I want to display the data on this kind of format:

```
|   Picture   |   ID   |       Name      |
|    Image    |   1    | Basilio, Rowell |
```

But when I execute the program it return results the following:

```
|   ID   |       Name      |
|   1    | Basilio, Rowell |
```

The `em_Picture` column data type is `"image"` and it was stored as `byte()` to the Database. I already search some solution on `Google` but doesn't help me.

Comment: You have to cast your return to a byte array... you dont have any code to show what you have tried doing to show where your having issues.

Comment: Let me confirm, did you suggest to cast or convert em_Picture to byte data type?

Comment: Use CType to cast your return value to a byte array...

Comment: But the problem is the 'Picture' column field is missing once I bind the SQL Script to 'DataGridView'.

Comment: This will explain more for you... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202836/Show-Hide-Image-in-DataGridView-Cell

Comment: Thanks for the link, as I check the code is based to Window based program and it was using C#. On the other hand, I was using Web based and my language is VB. On his case he was able to display the bytearray column but on my case I wasn't able to view the bytearray column I don't know why it is hidden.

Comment: That code is easy to convert. There are many free tools available online that will do this and your welcome!

Comment: Thanks anyway for your effort.. But sorry you didn't help me to my problem.. But I am still hoping that I can find the answer on my own..

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your return you can click to see the returned results... you should have that column with 'byte' in the cell. This has to be converted in order to show in the cell...